# Как написать функцию дешифровки к функции шифровки?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть такой код:

```
def encrypt(x, n): 
    key = 'qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazlfmhkb'

    if n == len(x):
        return ''.join(x)

    for i in range(n, len(x)):
        x[i] = chr(ord(x[i]) ^ ord(key[i - n]))  

    return encrypt(x, n + 1)

def encrypt_flag(flag):    
    return encrypt(list(flag), 0)    

flag = 'python'
enc_flag = encrypt_flag(flag)
print (repr(enc_flag))
```

Он только шифрует(если я правильно понял это шифр цезаря), надо написать функцию дешифровки, как это можно сделать(желательно с пояснениями)?

Comment: эта функция так же и расшифрует получившийся текст, попробуй

Comment: у вас там xor используется (оператор `^`), поэтому помещая результат шифрования с тем же ключом, получите обратный результат